# Change value of tuple based on data in other tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have two tuples

```py
A=[(1,Poland),(2,Canada),(3,Germany)]
B=[(1,16),(2,20),(3,54)]
```

How can i merge them together based on the first value of a tuple to get something like this

```py
C=[(Poland,16),(Canada,20),(Germany,54)]
```

I found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28814357/11868577) but this answer is from 2015 maybe you know better solution. My data will be at most 10/20 tuples so we aren't dealing with huge datasets

Comment: Are the couples of tuples always matching by index, or they can be shuffled? (Meaning that for example the `(1,16)` tuple in `B` will be second and not first)

Comment: They will be matching all the time

Comment: So what's the point of the first number?

Comment: `C=[(t1[1],t2[1]) for t1, t2 in zip(A,B)]`

Comment: The first number in A is index of a Country that is second value, First number in B is the index of Country and the second one is how many order's were from this country

Comment: I understand that, but if the couples are always matching, why do you need the first number? The index of the list can be the indicator. So instead of a list of tuples you can just have a list of countries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tuples are always ordered as in the example, this is an easy case and you can simply use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
C = []
for a,b in zip(A, B):
    C.append(a[1], b[1])

#  or simply C = [(a[1], b[1]) for a,b in zip(A, B)]
```

If the order is not guaranteed (which makes the first number actually necessary), I would first convert one list to a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), and then simply match the couples:

```py
b_dict = dict(B)
C = []
for i, country in A:
    C.append((country, b_dict[i]))

#  or C = [(country, b_dict[i]) for i, country in A]
```

Of course this might require some handling of edge cases but I will leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution.

```
[(x[1], y[1]) for y in B for x in A if x[0] == y[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This look like a problem for [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). You can turn them into `pandas.Series()` objects or `pandas.DataFrame()` and have the first number of the tuple as the index. Then just use the `pandas.DataFrame.merge()` to merge by index and you will have the three column dataframe or series.

Alternatively it would have to be a nested loop:

```
C = []
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        if i[0] == j[0]:
            C.append((i[1], j[1]))
```